# FFMPEG: How to reduce black sides in a vertical video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to rotate a vertical video using the below command

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf 'transpose=1,scale=-1:1080,pad=1920:1080:656:0,setsar=1' -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0  output.mp4`

While doing the playback ,most of the screen is occupied by black sides which FFMPEG has added.

Output image: [roated-video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo0Ey.png)

Is there any provision to reduce them?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pad filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf 'transpose=1,scale=-2:1080,setsar=1' -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, as per the ffmpeg documentation `scale=-2` is "not acceptable" . When tried with scale=1 , got the same result :(

Comment: Of course, it's acceptable. I use it often. Paste the full console output.

Comment: You're using a very old version (2013). Upgrade.